# MySQL inner join not returning all records

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have the following 5 tables

### appointments

| id | user_id | client_id | date | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 8 | 2022-04-19 | test |
| 2 | 4 | 16 | 2022-04-19 | test |
| 3 | 4 | 29 | 2022-04-19 | test |

### appointments_services

| id | appointment_id | service_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |

### clients

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | john | doe |
| 16 | john | doe |
| 29 | john | doe |

### users

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | john | doe |

### services

| id | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | visit | ff0000 |
| 10 | charge | ff0000 |

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.client_id, a.date, a.notes,

aserv.id AS asid,
aserv.appointment_id AS asappid,
aserv.service_id AS asservid,

c.id AS cid,
c.first_name AS cfirstname,
c.last_name AS clastname,

u.id AS uid,
u.first_name AS ufirstname,
u.last_name AS ulastname,

s.id AS sid,
s.name AS sname,
s.color AS scolor

FROM appointments AS a

INNER JOIN appointments_services AS aserv
ON a.id = aserv.id

INNER JOIN clients AS c
ON a.client_id = c.id

INNER JOIN users AS u
ON a.user_id = u.id

INNER JOIN services AS s
ON aserv.service_id = s.id
```

with the above query one row (appointment_id 3) will not display because it doesnt have a record in appointments_services table.

How can I change my sql query to display all records even if they dont have a connection within all tables?

Comment: You probably want to replace all inner joins with left join (`LEFT JOIN`).  Try that, and see if it gives you the behavior you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think the query now is much slower than before, is there any other way to try? there are more than 50000 records in the database

Comment: You may have to look into indexing your query.